# appendChild to an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, appendchild

The pains of learning something new. I have an array with 2 paragraphs. I am trying to insert a new  paragraph on the array after child zero. I got all the paragraphs on the page (they don't have ID's nor class names).

```
var allNodes = document.getElementById("article")
var paras = allNodes.getElementsByTagName("p")
var para=document.createElement("p");
var node=document.createTextNode("We welcome your feedback as we continue to evolve our website features to make doing business easier. Give us your feedback.");
para.appendChild(node);
paras[0].appendChild(para);
```

This is working but it places the new created paragraph inside an existing one not bellow it. How can I put it bellow the para[n] I want to? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use the `parentNode`:

```
paras[0].parentNode.insertBefore(para, paras[0].nextSibling);
```

**edit**: In my previous answer I checked for the existance of `.nextSibling`, and reverted to `appendChild` if it wasn't there [turns out this is not needed](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-insertBefore): *"If refChild is null, insert newChild at the end of the list of children."*.

Comment: Why the `if`? There's no error thrown using `insertBefore(node, node.nextSibling)` even in the absence of `node.nextSibling`.

Comment: Because in the only `DOM` specifications I found, ref_node is NOT optional, and there is no _defined_ behavior on a NULL node. Just because it works in most/all browsers I use, does not mean I can get sloppy... Or do you have a `DOM` specification which _explicitly_ states that if ref_node is `NULL` / `undefined`, it reverts to `appendChild`?

Comment: Hm, [at the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore). it _does_ state _"If referenceElement is null, newElement is inserted at the end of the list of child nodes."_, I can't find it at the W3C docs though, a little help before I convert to that answer?

Comment: That's the nearest thing I have to a reference for the behaviour; it might be worth checking out the official ECMAScript specs (if you *really* want to) though: http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php I wasn't planning to down-vote the use, though, or criticise; was just curious. :)

Comment: I used this: `paras[0].parentNode.insertBefore(para, paras[0].nextSibling)` and it did the trick. Than you Wrikken.

Comment: As am I, I've never known it could be done differently :) Found it on [DOM level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-insertBefore) already BTW: turns out you're totally correct that my solution is needlessly complex, I'll fix it, and thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad to have helped, and *thank you* for finding a concrete reference to back up MDN (which I've never encountered being wrong as yet, but it's nice to have a primary source to refer to). :)